# How to filter fact table in power bi on two columns using or operator?

Tags: powerbi, snowflake-schema, slicers

I'm new to power bi so I don't know much. I have created data warehouse with snowflake schema using Fifa World Cup 2022 source file from kaggle.com
Here are my tables in data warehouse
[tables from data warehouse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0WSWT.png)

Now, I would like to filter the fact table to get every row from that table based on a slicer that has countries. So if I click on country 'Bolivia' in the slicer, I need to filter the fact table to get me every match where Bolivia was either 'dim_domaci_tim'(home_team_id) or 'dim_gostujuci_tim'(away_team_id).
And based on that filter rows, I would like to create a card in power bi to show how many matches the team had played so far, what is their goalkeeper's average result and so on.

I tried using slicer and filtering the whole page in power bi base on the country that was selected but there is a problem because the query to filter that is wrong.